# Looking for feedback on kerning and custom type treatment

Tags: typography, logo, critique, branding, kerning

Working on a logo wordmark for a pasta fast food chain.

They wanted something very simple and typographic.

There will be a little grunge treatment after this but i first want to get the kerning and shapes right.

I started playing with this skewed white space in the A and between the E and T, i like it but it's maybe a bit 'demanding'.  I would love to know if the kerning is balanced and if the skewed line works as an element or works against the wordmark.
[image: This is the edited final edition]

[image: This is the original type, the client liked it but it was a bit to 'generic']

## Edit 1

I made the gap the same width, i'm not sure on whether it makes the spacing look a little to close between E and T. I also changed the font below to a different weight and decreased the space between A and V.
[image: update]

I also started playing around with different layouts for the letters.[image: different layouts for the logo]

## edit 2#

I rounded of the type so i did not look so agresive. Also played around with the kerning and baseline. What do you think of the rounded version in comparison to the angled ? Is the weight of the baseline better in a heavy weight or leight, i'm also playing with 2 fonts in the baseline ( the center one is Gill sans, the other 2 are both futura)

[image: Rounded version with different tagline weights]

Comment: Hi Stef, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Comment: I specified the question some more, is this sufficient ?

Comment: Thanks! With your edit, the questions has entered our 'reopen' queue, where users can vote whether they think it ok now. So have a bit of patience for the community to cast its vote :)

Comment: I prefer the top option, but the cut out on the A and between the E T should be the same width (in my opinion).  Also, are the lines in the A cutout perfectly parallel?  They don't appear to be.  There also looks like a tiny bit too much space between the A V.  Lastly, I would probably use the thinner font below the main logo, like you did on the bottom version.  Other than that, it looks good, to me.  If/when this gets re-opened, I'll visually demonstrate the changes that I would make.

Comment: Thank you @JohnManly for the tips! I edited the question a bit further. The A cutout was indeed a bit off, actually the lines were in general, i used the angle of the V and aligned all lines with that.

Comment: On your edit #1, top logo... maybe the kerning of the A and V could be a bit smaller again. I guess your logo is finished by now anyway ;)

Comment: I did another edit, because the client said it looked a bit to 'futuristic', so i rounded of some edges. I added an update .

Comment: I actually like the first one the best. Though the 'B' feels like it could be a tad closer to the rest. As for the rounding, I'm not entirely against it, but I think you over-did it. Maybe a very slight rounding to go with your 'grunging' later on to make it feel more like analog letterpress.

Comment: My suggestion for the direction for the brand is you go with a thick script fonts because they are fun and playful, you don't want to have serious and complex feeling when customers buy products or services from you client.

Comment: @Ngeshlew thanks for the advice! We finished the branding, you can see the final result in the link. We actually created a custom handwritten font to go with the logo to make it playful as you said. http://beta.clouddesign.be/case/bavet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will put this as the answer to the question.

My suggestion for the direction for the brand is you go with a thick script fonts because they are fun and playful, you don't want to have serious and complex feeling when customers buy products or services from you client.

If this helped you Stef, mark it as the answer.